# Python: Cannot print the right condition

Tags: python, python-requests, header, urllib

Why doesn't my code print the right condition?

I have a file called `mylist.txt` which contains two URLs:

```
https://google.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/
```

I should get **NO NO** answer for google and **200 Ok** for yahoo, but I get **NO NO** for both.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import urllib.request
import requests


with open('mylist.txt','r') as f:
    for mylist in f:
        print(mylist.rstrip())

        response = requests.get(mylist.rstrip())
        if response.status_code == '200':
            print("200 OK")
        else:
            print("NO NO")
```

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

```
response.status_code
```

returns an int. You are checking for a string.
Try this instead.

```
response.status_code
import urllib.request
import requests
with open('mylist.txt','r') as f:
    for mylist in f:
        response = requests.get(mylist.rstrip())
        print(type(response.status_code))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("200 OK")
        else:
            print("NO NO")
```

Comment: It still prints the wrong condition. Now both of them are ```200 OK```.

Comment: You should get a 200 ok. when connecting to google. What makes you think otherwise/

Comment: google should return ```NO NO``` and yahoo should return ```200 OK```.

Comment: But Why though lol. It really shouldn't. No No means requests couldn't connect to google.

Comment: When I use ```curl -I --url "https://google.com"``` it gives me 301 status code.